# C# - How is ctrl+A input turned into a smiley?

Tags: c#

While learning about Console.ReadLine() in depth, I found something very peculiar.

I wrote following code in Main method in a console application in C#

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.WriteLine(str.Trim());
Console.ReadLine();
```

When I ran the code, I gave input as ctrl+A and pressed enter. I see smileys (not able to post image, as I don't have permission to do it yet).

I want to understand, **how is it showing the smiley**? Shouldn't it show ^A or empty/blank (empty because when I tried debugging it, it showed string value a "  ".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at that Encoding used by Console then you can see that it is used IBM437.

Now go to page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

You will find that 1 has Smiley.

When you press ctrl + A , it will traslated into 1.

So you get that smiley.

```
        string str = Console.ReadLine();            
        Console.WriteLine((int)str[0]);  // Integer value of character.
        // Console.OutputEncoding ( to get further detail)
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)
Any place where I can look for mapping? Like ctrl+A =1, ctrl+G=7 and any other.

Answer (score 3):

The smiley is just how the console displays [U+0001](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0001/index.htm) (start of heading) - and that's the character that apparently is read as input from the console when you type Ctrl-A... a bit like the way that if you type Ctrl-G you get [U+0007](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0007/index.htm) (bell).

This isn't really .NET behaviour, so much as the Windows console behaviour (both input and output) - I can reproduce exactly the same behaviour in Java, for instance.

Comment: And typing `Alt+1` will do it in command prompt without any coding :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: That's presumably 1 on the numeric keypad, right? (I can't easily reproduce on my laptop...)

Comment: Yes, I belive "Alt+character code" requires numeric pad keys, not regular numbers. May be able to use 'Fn' button - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code

Comment: Thanks. There is another issue which I want to understand, once I press ctrl+Z the program breaks. Is it because of ctrl+Z (interrupt signal) is special? :)

Comment: @Abhishek: It's treating that as "end of data" I believe, closing standard input - so `ReadLine` returns `null`.